# Getting started developing an Adobe Premiere plugin?

Tags: adobe-premiere

How do I get started developing a Premiere Pro plugin? I have Premiere Pro CS3 and a working knowledge of VB.NET. (I have experience with a number of other languages that I can use to get around if need be.)

Is there an SDK that I'm looking for? Do I need to contact Adobe to join a developer program of sorts?

EDIT:

Silly me, I've found an SDK on Adobe's site. Where can I find an API or reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an SDK, no signup needed. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/premiere/sdk/cs3/.  The API docs come with the installer.

---

Edit (more info re: comments):

I don't know of any really good tutorials out there.  The best way to get started would be to try compiling some of the examples that come with Premiere SDK [using VC++, they all come with project files], then see if they work as expected.  There's a "Simple Video Filter" plugin in the examples that might be a good starting point.

It would probably also be helpful to get the After Effects SDK, as there are similarities between the two.  From Chapter 10 of the AE CS3 SDK Guide docs:

> Adobe Premiere Pro supports the After
>   Effects effect API. As of version 2.0,
>   Premiere Pro offers a thorough host
>   implementation, the key omissions
>   being 3D-related calls (auxiliary
>   channel information, cameras and
>   lights) and other utility functions
>   provided by After Effects’AEGP API.

If you haven't done a lot of C++ yet, [C++ in Action](http://www.relisoft.com/book/web_preface.html) is one of the better [online, free] introductions I've seen.  It might be too basic, but some of the plugin API stuff is pretty hairy, so a separate non-Adobe-API-related place to brush up on the language is probably a good idea.

Comment: Btw, got any personal work that you can share/pass along for me to look at?

Comment: All I've got is experimental AE stuff for my own pipeline, and it would probably be more confusing than helpful (in relation to the SDK examples) :)

Comment: I've seen your website. Is is supposed to be just a clickable logo?

Comment: The latest SDK API is found here: https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/premierepro.html